# Conditional logic in template email html wordpress CF7

Tags: html, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have use the conditional logic in a crm contact form form 7 using uacf7 conditional fields. Is it possible to insert them into my email template in html to display specific texts? Thanks

I use different methods using the names of the conditional logic created this way :
[name]
-- text to display --
[/name]
But when the email is sent, the condition is not verified and the execution code is displayed in the email

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not aware of a plugin that allows conditional email messages.  However, the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/#description) has a general mail tag that you can use and filter with a function and programmatically build your email message based on the submitted data.  See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcC36e69-eM&t=1255s) for more details.

Comment: Furthering the description as I'm looking for the same question and don't want to duplicate. We need conditionals in the Mail template construct *only*. Something like `[if:name]<span><br><table><whatever>[endif]` I also didn't find a plugin that does this to the email template.